# How to remove 1 instance of each (identical) line in a text file in Windows PowerShell and group the remaining identical lines?

Tags: powershell

There is an unsorted text file of about 100 million short lines:

```
Lucy 
Mary 
Mary 
Mary 
John 
John 
John 
Lucy 
Mark
Mary
```

I need to get

```
Mary 
Mary 
Mary 
John 
John 
Lucy
```

I cannot get the lines ordered according to how many times each line is repeated in the text, i.e. the most frequently occurring lines must be listed first.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Group-Object` to group equal lines together like below:

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\unsorted.txt' | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 }
    else { $_.Group }
} | Sort-Object -Descending
```

Result:

```
Mary 
Mary 
Mary
Mark
Lucy 
John 
John
```

---

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75002317/how-to-remove-1-instance-of-each-identical-line-in-a-text-file-in-windows-powe/75005307?noredirect=1#comment132362158_75005307) may have a point that 'Mark' should not be in the output and I may have misinterpreted the question (*remove one instance of each identical line*) in the above answer.

If that is correct, then the code can be even easier:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\unsorted.txt').Trim() | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 
} | Sort-Object -Descending
```

which will output

```
Mary
Mary
Mary
Lucy
John
John
```

Comment: @iRon Yes, you are probably right about that. I have edited my answer so unique lines will be removed from the output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$List = 'Lucy', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Lucy', 'Mark', 'Mary'
$Count = @{}
foreach ($Item in $List) { $Count[$Item]++ }
$Count.GetEnumerator() |Sort-Object -Descending 'Value' |
    ForEach-Object { ,$_.Name * ($_.Value - 1) }
```

```
Mary
Mary
Mary
John
John
Lucy
```

**Explanation**

- `$Count = @{}`
  Create a new hashtable
- `foreach ($Item in $List) { $Count[$Item]++ }`
  Count the repeating instances

  - starting from nothing (`$Null` + `1` => `1`)
- `$Count.GetEnumerator() |Sort-Object -Descending 'Value'`
  Sorts (descending) the hashtable based on the values
- `ForEach-Object { ,$_.Name * ($_.Value - 1) }`
  Iterate to the found instances

  - `,$_.Name` forces the string to an array
  - `... * ($_.Value - 1)` repeat the array 1 less times